# In a metric space, can one assume that a subset of finite diameter is always contained in some open ball?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In this thread([A basic question on diameter of a metric space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148838/a-basic-question-on-diameter-of-a-metric-space)) a user states a fact that I haven't been able to verify either by reading Rudin or by intuition. he states: "A nonempty subset S⊆X having finite diameter is equivalent to SS being contained in some ball B(x,r) for some x∈X and some r>0" Is this always the case and if so why? ( I did not understand his reasoning.)

Thanks for your time

Comment: The title doesn't really reflect the question. Also note that the diameter as defined by Rudin is a number, not a set.

Comment: Apologies, you are correct. I have updated the question removing the Rudin definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Archemidean Axiom (or as a theorem dependent on the set of axioms for the real system) plays the role, from which it follows that for every real number there is a greater one. By the definition of the diameter $l(S)$ of a set $S$ of a metric space we know that the distance between any two elements of $S$ is at most $l(S)$. So you can use an open ball of diameter $r\cdot l(S)$ to contain $S$ for some real $r$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Thank you so much @Eric Clapton, if my newfound understanding is right then there is no way that a subset of a finite diameter could be closed, correct? Since that ball, you mentioned, of diameter l(S) must be open. Apologies if this is redundant. the idea of the diameter being defined this way is sadly confusing on my part.

Comment: A subset of finite diameter can be closed. Ex: Unit circle in $R^2$.

Comment: No worries. I guess the confusion may just come from that the concept of supremum is not yet that real to you :) (I myself had such a hard time when first exposed to that concept). Your inference is not correct. The set $[0,1]$ is of finite diameter, but it is closed. The open ball $]-1, 2[$ contains $[0,1]$. Sorry I committed a typo in my answer. If $S$ is closed and if an open ball $B$ is required to contain $S$, then $B$ of diameter $l(S)$ is not sufficient :).

Comment: @YunusSyed  and Eric Clapton Thank you both very much, I was actually constantly thinking about the unit circle as a counter, however, as you mentioned Eric whenever I think about the diameter it's hard to picture it being closed, at least intuitively speaking. Thanks everyone who contributed to this thread.

Comment: @bof, Thank you. My mistake. I did not treat rigorous enough.

Comment: I think you corrected more than you needed to. Seems to me any diameter $\gt2l$ suffices, seeing as you can cover it with an *closed* ball of radius $l.$.

Comment: @bof, Yes. I took the safest action possible possibly :).